# xml of a layer on geoserver is different when I am opening it in browser

Tags: geoserver, xml, geoserver-rest-api

xml of a layer on a geoserver is different when I am opening it in browser, for example:

http://mygeoserver/geoserver/rest/services/wfs/transforms/layer_test.xml

it look like this:

```
<transform>
<name>layer_test</name>
<sourceFormat>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</sourceFormat>
<outputFormat>HTML</outputFormat>
<fileExtension>html</fileExtension>
<xslt>layer_test.xslt</xslt>
</transform>
```

and when I open xml file in notepad it looks like:

```
<transform>
    <sourceFormat>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</sourceFormat>
    <outputFormat>HTML</outputFormat>
    <outputMimeType>text/html</outputMimeType>
    <fileExtension>html</fileExtension>
    <xslt>layer_test.xslt</xslt>
    <featureType>
        <id>schema:layer_test</id>
    </featureType>
</transform>
```

I'm missing part with the featuretype. What can be cause of it, am I searching on wrong place?

Comment: In general don't edit (or even look at) the raw xml files unless you know what you are doing. The feature type is not something you should (or can) change via the REST api so it is not passed out by the REST API.

Comment: @IanTurton Tnx for your comment, but its not idea to change anything, I just want to get list of layers, xml and xslt files, and some parameters  to check the current state on the geoserver. As it can happen, there can be some lost xslt which later creates problems